# Enable/disable TextBox on FormView.ModeChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, formview

I have  `DropDownList` and a `TextBox` in the `EditTemplate` of my `FormView`. All I want is to enable/disable the `TextBox` based on whether the first entry of my `DropDownList` is selected:

1. When the `FormView` is switched to **Edit** mode by the user
2. When user changes the selected item of the `DropDownList` during **Edit** mode.

I have achieved the second one through JS and that's working fine, but the first one is proving too difficult. I've tried to do this in `ModeChanged` event of the `FormView`, but for some reason the following call returns `null` in the event:

```
MyFormView.FindControl("MyDropDownListID");
```

What am I missing here?

(I'm making sure that  `MyFormView.CurrentMode` is `FormViewMode.Edit` before making the above call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of those times when you pull your hair for hours with a problem, then post it on SO and find the solution in the next few minutes. Anyone else trapped into this, the problem is that the controls of a databound `FormView` aren't created yet at the time of `ModeChanged` or `Page_Load`. You must call the above line in `DataBound` event and it will work fine.